# can't compile for release, can for debug? [iphone]

Tags: iphone, xcode, release, libxml2

I'm trying to compile my project, containing cocos2d and standard UIKit part, i'm trying to do this for iphone 3g/3Gs.
The problem is, when i'm building it for debug configuration, it goes like on butter (no errors). But, when i switch to release, i've got over 1300 errors, all of them are like:

[printscreen](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/5371/zrzutekranu20100901godz.png)

almost all of them contain problem with libxml.

What i'm doing wrong? If some body knows this , please share this priceless knowledge:)
thanks in advance

p.s. i'm using also ToushXML in UIKit part

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the include path is different set for debug and release, have you checked that in your project settings? It may be missing for release.